# Подключение ffmpeg в NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, ffmpeg

Не получается слинковать ffmpeg библиотеки в NetBeans.
Указал путь для дополнительных библиотек, указал сами библиотеки, а в результате undefined reference:

```
g++ -m32 -static -mwindows    -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/test1 build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/Programms/MinGW/ffmpeg/lib -lavdevice.dll -lavformat.dll
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `avdevice_register_all()'
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3e2): undefined reference to `av_register_all()'
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x484): undefined reference to `avdevice_register_all()'
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x489): undefined reference to `av_register_all()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Окно настроек линковщика:
[image: Окно настроек линковщика]
Также пробовал вместо выбора файлов библиотек прописать в дополнительных параметрах строки компиляции `-lavdevice -lavformat` - находит без ошибок, но всё равно undefined reference. При этом в свойствах компилятора указал пути к include и редактор не подчёркивает красным функции ffmpeg, даже предлагает их по ctrl+space. Инклуды прописаны:

```
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```

В чём может быть проблема? Это "битая" сборка ffmpeg или я что-то упустил?

PS: может там что-то связано с pkg-config?

Answer (score 1):

Блин, 3 часа убил на поиск ответа. Оказалось, что include надо было завернуть:

```
extern "C"{
    #include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
```

Может кому пригодится...